# New a UIPickerView from storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, picker

My question is as follows. Is it posible to re-create a UIPickerView created in the story board? I have created a UIPickerView in storyboard and i need to nil that UIPickerView and re-create it again. I just want to know if this can be done somehow with restoration id perhaps?

.. or do i need to create the UIPickerView from code only...?

............... reason why i must nil the UIPickerView is to completely stop the user from spinning the wheel at fast speed, when closing the wheel and reopening the UIPickerView again fast. When this is done the wheel keeps spinning when user opens UIPickerView again. If you force the UIPickerView to select a value the UIPickerView still continues to scroll so that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving a strong reference to the picker view, removing it from it's superview then adding it back.

I just tried it, and this code works:

```
- (IBAction)handleButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
  UIPickerView *thePicker = _spinner;
  [thePicker removeFromSuperview];
  [self.view addSubview: thePicker];
}
```